# SELECT across two tables - not sure if join or union?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1. que - which contains `bot_id` and `player_id`
2. bot_inventory - which contains `bot_id` and `item_id`

What I would like to have output from a query is a list grouped by bot_id's which has one column count(`player_id`) and another count(`item_id). This should be only based on the bot_id's found in que.

I've had a go at it:

```
SELECT `que`.`bot_id`,
       Count(`que`.`player_id`)         AS players,
       Count(`bot_inventory`.`item_id`) AS items
FROM   `que`
       LEFT JOIN `bot_inventory`
              ON `que`.`bot_id` = `bot_inventory`.`bot_id`
ORDER  BY `que`.`bot_id`
```

But it's not coming out right :/ any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a base bots table where `bot_id` is the pk?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @lc. no I don't unfortunately.

Comment: @hd1 not really an error - more so the query not giving me the correct output. it wasn't accounting for all bot_id's in que.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the "it's not coming out right".  I take that to mean that the values returned by the `COUNT` aggregate is larger than you expect. The reason for that is a row from `que` is getting matched to multiple rows from `bot_inventory`, and that COUNT aggregate is going to count the rows, and not the distinct players.

If `(bot_id,player_id)` is unique in the que table, then one simple fix to the "players" count would be add the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT q.player_id) as players,
```

The same pattern applies to the "items" count, again, if that is unique.

Actually, it looks like your query is also missing a

```
GROUP BY que.bot_id
```

(which is the problem juergen d pointed out in his answer, and I missed that at first.)

Otherwise, you could rewrite the query to use inline views to get the counts, e.g.

```
SELECT q.bot_id
     , q.players
     , b.items
  FROM ( SELECT p.bot_id, COUNT(p.player_id) AS players
           FROM que p
          GROUP BY p.bot_id
       ) q
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT d.bot_id, COUNT(d.item_id) AS items
           FROM bot_inventory d
          GROUP BY d.bot_id
       ) b
    ON b.bot_id = q.bot_id
 ORDER BY q.bot_id
```

Comment: your code block works perfectly (except for the one error where you GROUP BY q.bot_id instead of p.bot_id) thank you very much!

Comment: @user2504897: DOH! my bad.  once you found the error, it was an easy fix. You can run each of the inline view queries (aliased as q and b) for testing. The outer query will eliminate rows from b which don't have matching bot_id returned in `q`.